# Open file inside Python

Tags: python-2.7, terminal

How can I open a file once I am inside Python, that is, once I have typed "python" in the terminal? I know how to open a file by typing something similar to the following in a script, and then running it:

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

But I have no idea how to do it once I'm inside the Python interpreter. I've tried to type **open (file.txt)** and also **open ("file.txt")**, but I get a long error message either way.

Which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a mode to the call `txt = open('filename.txt', 'r')` if you want to read (or `w`/`a` for writing or appending). I just tried it, it works :)